# can not override the text box in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have one text box in the page. When i load the page i retrieved value from db and show in text box. I enter tab to move another text box and tab again to first text box.Edit the value. First value is Test. I edited Test 50. Remove the Test 50 value and and tab again. It shows the First value Test. But i need the edited value Test 50. I am not using any mask text box. Could you please provide the suggestion? FYI the same thing happened on our Tags when post the question in stack overflow.

Thanks,
Guvera